# EPS is not a font file, right?

Tags: fonts, eps, typeface

Well someone who has made a rather amazing-looking font has also made if available for free download, which is nice.  Unfortunately, however, this person seems to have convinced himself that .EPS is a font file, which, of course, it is not. What am I missing here? How can I make this image file into a font file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

EPS stands for Encapsulated PostScript. It's not a font file, but it *can* contain fonts. Normally, PS or EPS files contain text, formatting info, images, etc. The fonts you are seeing could be either

- real fonts, and the text that uses them, or
- drawings of the fonts

In the first case, the author can decide to include the fonts (if they are unique and necessary) or fall back on system fonts.

It is generally not easy to extract fonts from that file, as they are possibly compressed. And they could also be incomplete, containing only the glyphs for the characters necessary.

If you really like the fonts, and are willing to do the work, there are font editors which can take a screenshot and convert the outline into a glyph. They can then organize the glyphs into a font. It's a lot of work, but hey, if you like graphics design, it *is* possible.

A final comment. Are you sure there isn't a separate font file in the package? At times, font authors include PS, or PDF files to show the font, and separately include the .ttf file.

**Good news**: I just noticed that there is a Windows version of Fontforge, which is an excellent font editor, though somewhat complicated, and which I've used for some design work. Fontforge is able to import glyphs from Inkscape, which is able to open .eps files!

So, you can open your .eps in Inkscape, scale and edit it, and, following the instructions in the FAQ of FontForge scale the glyphs in such a way that it is easy to put them into a font file.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to hunt for one of those programs then! And no, no other files or formats; I've hunted that man's website and many others very thoroughly.